# htop interpetation of multiple entries per process

Tags: process, htop

In the following `htop` snapshot, what is the meaning of multiple entries of the **same** process (in terms of command line, not `pid`)

e.g. what is the meaning of having say more than 7-8 `firefox` entries with more or less the same command seeming to be used?

Is there a way to restrict the `htop` view to single entry per process?

[image]

Comment: That Firefox runs separate processes for various things?

Comment: thx; what if I want to have an `htop` view of firefox as a whole? (CPU, memres, memvirt etc?) is this possible?